# Android Google Place Picker autocomplete not showing nearby places

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-places-api

I use Google Place API in my app and I have a little issue with Place Picker autocomplete feature.

The autocomplete feature does not show nearby places, but places all around the world. For example when I search mcdonald it will show me McDonalds in the USA whereas I'm in France.

The interactive map with its list of nearby places are working great on the other hand, I can see nearby places. The issue is only with autocomplete feature.

I tried to set a LatLngBounds to the builder, but the result is the same. The interactive map is affected by the LatLngBounds but the autocomplete feature is not.

I don't know if it is the normal beahvior or not, the documentation on Place Picker is not really precise and does not mention that.

And I didn't see either in the doc if there is an option to disable autocomplete feature.

Do you guys have some recommandations for me ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `location`and `radius` parameters, and try searching again, e.g;

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Mcdonalds&key=API_KEY&location=48.992899,%202.522523&radius=100000
```

For more information https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete

Comment: This seems to be broken on Android currently (at least in the latest bits provided by Xamarin) while it's working on iOS. Specifying the radius is respected for the map, but ignored to text input in the autocomplete search box.

Comment: @PhilippSumi i use this method in iOS and Android both . it work perfect

Comment: Harshil - are you using Xamarin? If yes, could you let us know which version? I'm on the latest and greatest, and there's not much I can do other than try out other versions... Thanks!

Comment: no i work on native app (android and iOS) . never work in Xamarin